# Breaking Integrals by Multiplication

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I know that in general, you cannot break the integral up under multiplication. That is:

$\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)g(x)dx} \neq \int_{a}^{b}{f(x)dx}\int_{a}^{b}{g(x)dx}$

for most functions. Are the any functions $f(x),g(x)$ where

$\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)g(x)dx} = \int_{a}^{b}{f(x)dx}\int_{a}^{b}{g(x)dx}$

holds? I am sure this will not hold for polynomial functions (since power rule will give different degrees for the resulting classes of polynomials on both sides of the equality), but I wasn't sure if there could be a clever choice of integrable functions to make this true.

Comment: You should avoid using $\ast$ for multiplication---this symbol is usually reserved for convolution in this setting.

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you for the reminder.

Comment: In general the LHS is defined up to a multiplicative constant $C$ but the RHS is defined up to two different constants. It will be necessary to add constraints to the integration bounds to avoid this. Once you have added integration bounds this becomes (what seem to me as a) a hard but interesting problem

Comment: That is a good point! Let's assume that there are bounds.

Comment: It’s worth noting that for any $f$ there is a one dimensional family of $g$ such that $(xy)’ = x’y’$ so we should expect for any fixed $f$ here a rich family of solutions $g$

Comment: I made the bounds explicit in my most recent edit of the question. That is a good point about the derivatives. I will explore more with that idea.

Comment: @PatrickGambill you will probably enjoy [this](https://youtu.be/eYFJV3Fatqk?si=tukmQ5zmu5bBH9sC) video

Comment: Trivially, this would be true for $f(x)=0$ and any $g$, or $f(x)=1/$ if $b-a=1$.

Comment: Also, $f=\sin(n x)$ and $g=\sin (mx)$, $n\neq m$, and $a=0$, $b=2\pi$.

Comment: That is  good point. I wonder if this can be extended to other sets of orthogonal functions, if the bounds are chosen appropriately.